# Problems with deserializing JSON to class

Tags: apex, json, error, rest

I have created a parser  class to parse some JSON into an object.  This is accessible as a REST based service.

This is the class I parse to:

```
global class statParser {



    global class Request {
    global String sfId;
    global List<MResult> mResult;
    global List<TResult> tResult;
}


global class MResult {
    global String strsfId;
    global String Score;
}



global class VResult {
    global String message;
    global String mapping;

}
 global Request request;
}
```

Here is the class that does the parsing.  It contains this function:

```
public static statParser parse(String json) {
    return (statParser) System.JSON.deserialize(json, statParser.class);
  }
```

And here is the relevant code for manipulation:

```
global static void UpdateFromService(String M_JSON){

statParser eb_res = parse(M_JSON);

system.debug(eb_res);

....
}
```

My problem is that whenever I call this function directly when executing anonymous apex using this string

```
{ "request": { "sfId": "001M000000yJLryIAG", "mResult": [], "vResult": []}}
```

It parses correctly and I can see the primitives in the class that have data.  But when I try to to call it by POSTing the same JSON string to the function as @HttpPost (it's setup as a REST based service that does the sae thing as the code above) I get a generic JSON parser error which I can't figure our why.  I'm sending the data as Content-Type:  application/json  .  Any idea why the JSON parser error shows up?

Comment: Pretty sure that JSON is case sensitive. Have you verified that your mResult and vResult keys are correct? I can see `MResult` on the object and `mResult` on the JSON.... same for `vResult`.

Comment: But JSON parser would simply ignore the string, if they are not exact match with custom variable names in the Inner class. What JSON error are you getting?

Comment: I think every variable in your inner class must be present in the JSON payload (or vice versa, can't remember from top of my head) if you're deserialising that way.

Comment: @BorisBachovski - Thats only with Deserialize Strict. It changed way back in API v2x something

Comment: @akarnid - You provided us with all the code that DOES work but provided nothing that does not. Please update with your code you are using to POST, the HttpPost rest resource method, the debug of the JSON string in that method, etc. Then we can help. Most likely there is something is how you are passing the string to the post etc but no way to tell unless we see that code. And may need the `parse` method as well since that is not shown either

Comment: Instead of parsing the JSON why don't you directly accept `List<Wrapper>` as a parameter. Like this: `global static void UpdateFromService(List<Request> lstRequest){`

Comment: Rohit this is a REST based service that accepts JSON.  Wouldn't I have to deserialize the JSON first to get a list of Requests?

Comment: Eric, the     parse method is shown above.  It's just a standard deserialize action that casts it to a class instance, like Superfell's JSON2Apex does out of the box.